# AWS-Amplify V6 Upgrade Causes ‘User Unauthenticated’ Error After Deployment but Works Locally

Tags: reactjs

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I recently upgraded to AWS-Amplify V6 for my project. Everything works fine when I run the application on my local host, but I encounter an issue after deploying it.

Problem:
After deployment, I consistently receive a ‘User Unauthenticated’ error. This issue does not occur when I’m running the application locally, which makes it more perplexing.

What I’ve tried:

```
1.  Checked and reconfigured the authentication settings in AWS-Amplify.
2.  Ensured that all environment variables are correctly set in the deployment environment.
3.  Cross-verified the user pool IDs and other related settings between the local and deployed environments.
```

Question:
Has anyone encountered a similar issue after upgrading to AWS-Amplify V6? What might be causing this discrepancy between the local and deployed environments? Any suggestions for troubleshooting or resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Additional Information:

```
•   AWS-Amplify Version: 6.x
•   Deployment platform: [mention your deployment platform, e.g., AWS, Heroku]
•   Authentication method used: [e.g., Cognito, OAuth]
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Feel free to modify this template to include more specific details about your setup, which could help others in providing more accurate solutions.